# javascript append value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a noob with javascript. I've been searching the internet with google, but no answer helps me.
I have a database id that must be sent in an modal form as a hidden value.

```
echo "<a class='label label-warning' id='".$bl_total['id']."' **<< this id**
data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>".$bl_total['id']."</a>";

<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="9999" /> **<< must replace the 9999**
```

**JS :**

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var id = $("a").val();
    $("#id").val(id);
});
```

Comment: Try `$("a").text();`

Comment: use $("a").on('click', function(){

Comment: $("a").click(function() {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $("#id").val(id);
    }); Works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers will get you what you want, but a slightly cleaner alternative is

```
$('a').click(function () {
  $('#id').val(this.id);
});
```

Note a couple things:

1. `this.id` is more performant and readable than both `$(this).text()` or `$(this).attr('id')`. It bypasses jQuery completely and accesses the `id` property of the `<a>` element.
2. If your code is in the order you have written, `$(document).ready(...)` is unnecessary, since the script is evaluated after the relevant HTML has been parsed and the DOM rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
<script>
$("a").click(function() {
  var id = $("a").text();
  $("#id").val(id);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve id using `attr('id')` then replace value of hidden input using `.val()`, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click', 'a', function() {
        var link_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#id").val(link_id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='label label-warning' id='11111' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Link example</a>
<br>
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="9999" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in `$(document).ready()` and to get text from `<a>` use `text()` not `val`. `val` is used for `input` element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
       var id = $(this).text();
       $("#id").val(id);
    });
});
```